# Optimally Efficient Tournament Strategies

Tags: probability, game-theory

Consider a fair symmetric game between two players that always results in exactly one of the players winning, *i.e.* there are no ties.

When two players $P$ and $Q$ play each other, $P$ wins with a fixed but unknown probability $W_{PQ}$.

In a collection $n$ players, each player $P$ has an unknown score $S_P = \frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{Q \neq P} W_{PQ}$. It is the arithmetic mean of $P$'s win probability over all other players. Assume that no two players have the same score.

I want to rank all players in the collection by their score, using the minimum number of games. Since the outcome of each game is based on a probability, I can never be fully confident of the ranking. However, I am interested in finding two particular tournament strategies:

1. A strategy which returns a ranking with confidence $c$ (e.g. 90%) using the fewest number of games.
2. A greedy strategy which increases confidence by as much as possible with each game.

I feel like this is a known and solved problem, but I haven't been able to find the solution. Some of my terminology might be off or clumsy. I'd welcome edits in those cases.

Comment: How do you define "with confidence $c$"? There is a combinatorial aspect that makes that a little tricky to pin down and is likely to make the problem difficult to solve in any great generality without additional assumptions: Namely, what if there are groups of players with the same score?

Comment: As a separate aside, if some structure on $W_{PQ}$ is assumed, then I think some tangible progress may not be too difficult. For example, in the [Bradley-Terry model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison#Probabilistic_models) it is known that the coefficients fit by maximum likelihood will yield the same ranking as that obtained from simply looking at the winning percentage of each player *when a full round-robin is played* (or, multiple ones).

Comment: That's a good point. Does the same problem exist if the players have scores which are distinct but may be arbitrarily close together?

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you for that link!

Comment: I think studying the uniform case $W_{PQ} = 1/2$ could be a good starting point in exploring whatever definition of confidence you consider since, in some sense, *any* returned ranking is valid.

Comment: Though only vaguely related, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6701/2970) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15776/2970) are a couple of answers I've given previously on aspects of Bradley-Terry. There is also a famous book by H. A. David entitled *[The method of paired comparisons](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_method_of_paired_comparisons.html?id=ECo4AAAAMAAJ)* and the article [Tournaments and paired comparisons](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2332816) by the same author.